# What does the leading part of Bash's default PS1 in Ubuntu mean?

Tags: bash, prompt, escape-characters

This is the `$PS1` of my Bash shell on a freshly installed Ubuntu 18.04:

```
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\] \$
```

I can well understand every other part of the prompt:

- `${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}`: If it's set, show it, but add parentheses around it; if unset, show nothing
- `\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\] \$`: Standard `user@host:cwd $` prompt with colors enabled using CSI escape sequences

I'm confused about the first part:

```
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]
```

AFAIK, `\[` and `\]` expands to `\001` and `\002` to tell GNU readline that the characters between them should not be counted for "length of prompt". The question would boil down to the meaning of this:

```
\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a
```

It's `<ESC>]0;user@host: cwd<ALARM>`. What does that do? (Note: CSI is `<ESC>[` not `<ESC>]`, or I would have understood)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an [XTerm escape sequence](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Xterm-Title-3.html#ss3.1), which sets the icon name and window title. It is supported by most graphical terminal emulators (and some non-graphical terminal emulators too).